# Count MySQL rows with values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to count how many rows in my MySQL database have two certain values. My table is set up like this:

```
|---------------------|
|         ids         |
|---------------------|
|source_id | target_id|
|----------|----------|
|        2 |         6|
|        2 |         6|
|        3 |         4|
|---------------------|
```

I want to count how many rows have the `source_id = 2` and `target_id = 6`
I tried this statement:

```
<?php
$prep_stmt = "SELECT source_id FROM ids WHERE source_id = 2 AND target_id = 6";
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($prep_stmt)) {
    die("Failed");
} else {
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    echo $num_rows;
}
?>
```

However, the PHP file ceases to function after the third line.

Comment: *it doesn't work.* is not diagnostically helpfull

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really know what to write.. After the third line nothing in the PHP file works anymore. The page is blank in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ids WHERE source_id=2 AND target_id=6`

Comment: No worries :) read [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html), COUNT() is very useful

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks a bit weird. **If** you want to use prepared statements, that's working totally differentely:

```
<?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ids` WHERE `source_id` = ? AND `target_id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $source_id, $target_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo $count;
```

And without prepared statements.

```
<?php

echo $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ids` WHERE `source_id` = 2 AND `target_id` = 6");
```

And as a last note, if you asign **anything** within a condition be sure to enclose it in brackets:

```
<?php

function fn() {
  return "something";
}

if (($foo = fn())) {
  // The condition is true if $foo isset, or in other words not null after the function was called.
}

if (!($foo = fn())) {}

if (($foo = fn()) === null) {}

// ...
```

Comment: I've never known to do that.. so it should be `if (!($result = $mysqli->query($prep_stmt))) {}` ? Also, I'm using a variable for the statement because I have an array of statements as I am making multiple queries in this file that aren't relevant to this question. I'm very new to MySQL so thank you so much!

Comment: Exactly, that's how it should be written. This ensures that the function call and assignment is performed before the condition check. This is also very important for casts for example. You should never execute queries in a loop, you're doing something seriously wrong if you are doing that and should revise your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ids WHERE source_id = 2 AND target_id = 6";
```

will give you the number of entries corresponding to what you want.

(it will give one row with 1 column, containing the number of lines corresponding to the where close)